# How do I change 0's to missing value?

Tags: sas

I have 3 variables with me EXample: A B and C all of them have many 0 as their values. Can someone help me out how to convert 0's to missing value in sas?

This is how my values look

```
 A    B    C
21    55   0
0     59   88
0      0    77
32     0   39
44     55   0
```

I need to change all the 0 to missing values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scalable approach is store the values in an array, loop through each value and perform the required changes.
I'd also question the purpose of doing this.  If it is for a report then simply do a PROC FORMAT to display zeros as missing.

```
data have;
modify have;
array vars{*} A B C; /* or _numeric_ if you want all numeric variables */
do i = 1 to dim(vars);
    if vars{i}=0 then call missing(vars{i});
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply set them to missing (which is represented as a ".");

```
IF A=0 THEN A=.;
IF B=0 THEN B=.;
IF C=0 THEN C=.;
```

You can read about working with missing values here:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002316433.htm

Comment: hi, I have updated my question. Can you pls help me out in changing the values to missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'call missing' function, details can be found here:

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002558398.htm